# Finding Taylor Series of Indefinite Integral $\cos(x^2)$ around $x = 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How would I find the Taylor series around $x = 0$ for this integral?

$$\int \cos(x^2)$$

My first point of confusion is if it is around $x = 0$, doesn't that make it a Maclaurin series?

Would I go about finding the higher order derivatives of $\int \cos(x^2)$ while substituting $x=0$ for each derivative until I find a pattern to then substitute into the Taylor series formula?

Comment: Maclaurin series are Taylor series.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int\cos(x^2)dx&=\int\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{4n}}{(2n)!}\right)dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\int x^{4n}dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!(4n+1)}x^{4n+1}+C.
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh, I think I see. You can just insert the power series for cosx into the integral, and then compute? And the series excluding x^4n is taken out of the integral because its a coefficient?